# Convert 2 bytes or 3 bytes to a float in C

Tags: c, floating-point

I'm working with a low-level protocol that has a high data rate and therefore uses 2 or 3 bytes to represent a `float` depending on the range of the number, to make the system more efficient.

I'm trying to parse these numbers but the values I get don't make sense to me, they're all zero and I don't think the device would output zero for the variables in question.

The first 5 bytes in my buffer are: `FF-FF-FF-FF-FF`

The first two bytes make up a `float t`. It should be noted that the documentation says that the bytes are little endian.

To parse `t` I do:

```
float t = 0;
memcpy(buffer, &t, 2);
```

The next 3 bytes make up `float ax`, to parse that I do:

```
float ax = 0;
memcpy(buffer+2, &ax, 3);
```

Is this the correct way to handle this? I set both `t` and `ax` to zero first in case there are random bytes hanging around.

**Update**

The documentation is not great. Firstly they define a `Float` as a `32-bit IEEE 754 floating-point number`.

Then there is this quote:

```
To increase efficiency many of the data packets are sent as 24-bit signed integer words 
because 16-bits do not provide the range/precision required for many of the quantities, 
whereas 32-bit precision makes the packet much longer than required.
```

Then there is a table which defines `t` as the first 2 bytes of the buffer. It states that the range is 0-59.999. It doesn't explicitly say that it's a `Float`, I'm just making that assumption.

Comment: If you are talking about binary16 [half-precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-precision_floating-point_format), you cannot simply copy bytes to a binary32 [single precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format). You must manage the conversion. I never heard something about 3 bytes floats...

Comment: I agree with @LPs here. IEEE-754 is generally used to represent a floating point number. You cannot just read the lowest `n` bytes of a floating point number and assume that you've picked the number to `x` precision. For more info see https://thirum.al/2dk4tx9

Comment: C is a pain for this kind of thing: UB is only a stone's throw away. You're surely building to a very specific platform here: a 3 byte float is funky. I'd consider a couple of lines of inline assembly if I were you: do you have a 3 byte register?

Comment: Somewhere in the spec of your low-level protocol, the exact format of these floating point numbers should be defined: how many bits for the exponent, how many for the mantissa, how signs of each are represented?

Comment: What do the bytes contain? I've never heard of 3 byte floats. It's not impossible to do, but almost certainly this is a very application specific format. I've done 46 bit (yes, 46, not a typo) floats when I needed to squeeze out the most from an on-disk storage format, but then the encoding and decoding was done manually all the way by shifting bits around and I made very conscious decisions about how many bits mantissa and exponent to save. I suspect something like this is going on here. Surely there must be more in the documentation than just "3 byte float".

Comment: You'll need to find the documentation for the protocol you are using and read its specification for how it converts floats to 24-bit representations

Comment: @Kells1986 could you add some additional bytes after the first 5 bytes displayed. Often the use of 0xFFFFFF...FF could be a NaN floating point encoding.

Comment: I am guessing this is MCOM format for GPS by OxTS.... I recognise the statement about 16bit and 24bit. I think you will find ALL 24bit variables are signed integers, all floats are 32bit and doubles are 64bit. There is no 24 bit float. Why don't you tell us what you are doing (what hardware /device is sending this data) and what the documentation actually says for the packet/channel you are trying to decode.

Comment: Also the part about it being 0 to 59.999 means that its an integer of 2 bytes, the values 0 to 59999 as an integer represent 00.000 to 59.999 for the field in question (ie. you are meant to add the decimal place yourself, its not a float). The fact that it is all 0xFF bytes probably means your read failed and/or the field is not populated. I know some of those MCOM GPS fields are set to 0xFF when there is no valid data for the field.

Answer (score -3):

Possibly you have the arguments the wrong way around. Change as follows:

```
memcpy (buffer, &t, 2);
```

to

```
memcpy (&t, buffer, 2);
```

HTH

[edit: To clarify to all those people voting my answer down, the question does indeed have the arguments the wrong way around. Tries to read the buffer but specifies it as the destination for memcpy]

Comment: Not a downvoter, but copy bytes from a half-precision float to a single-precision float does not work....

Comment: @LPs I understand, but the OP doesn't know why he is getting all zeros. Until he actually reads from his buffer he won't know why the memcpy doesn't work for floats.